# Display Activity A data in Activity B page

Tags: android

I have 2 textbox,1 spinnerview and 1 button in this Activity A. After the user click the button, it goes to next Activity B which i want this activity to display what the user have type in the 2 textbox, choosing spinner view. How to do this? Activity B is sort of a Confirmation page of what the user typed in Activity A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
i.putExtra("data", editText.getText().toString());
startActivity(i);
```

Then in ActivityB in `onCreate()`:

```
String data = getIntent().getStringExtra("data");
showConfirmation(data);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass data into your intent which is starting the Activity B.

Check this for more info.

http://thedevelopersinfo.wordpress.com/2009/10/15/passing-data-between-activities-in-android/