# how to get the value from a xml parser to an other class

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, baseadapter

I'm searching all over the internet, but I didn't find anything, I could use. So here is my problem: I have an xml parser that works in an list view, but I want to give the id of the song to an other activity , so I can display it.

Comment: "I'm searching all over the internet" try searching on stackoverflow. you may find, for instance, this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229596/display-activity-a-data-in-activity-b-page question that quite answers yours.

Comment: it doesn't because when i tryed that i got the value of the string that i gave in the begining of the class

Comment: did you try to put something in your intent when you start Test activity ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** First you need `OnItemClickListener()` method for `ListView`

**2.** Then once you capture the `index of the row` on which you clicked, use `Intent()` to pass it to another activity.

**Note:**

`For this to work, please make the Map as static, and please do map.clear() , everytime before loading the Map with parsed data.`

**3.** When you go to the another `Activity`, I hope the Order of your Song in `Map` and in the `ListView` are same,

So Suppose you pressed the 2nd item on the `ListView`, the index passed will be 1, and in other `Activity` just call the `Map's` 1st index.

**Note:**

**Adding header will effect the index** of `ListView` so its better to use `getItemIdAtPosition(arg)` in the `onClick()` method.

**Eg:**

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.MyListView);

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {

                i = new Intent(ProductActivity.this, ProductDetails.class);


                i.putExtra("keyAapo", (int) lv.getItemIdAtPosition(arg2));

                startActivity(i);

            }

        });
```

Comment: i did that but how do i get the "getItemIdAtPosition(arg2)" to the other class because what i now see is: Intent {cmp=package.name/className(has extras)} any eplonations

Comment: @PieterTielemans On the other activity do something like this..................... `Intent i = getIntent();  String songName = intent.getExtras().getString("songKey");`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass by using `setTag()` and `getTag()` methods look at my answer here[How to acces variable in arrayadapter getView from onItemClick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12619178/964741)

Answer (score 0):

The Intent extra passing option was already said, however, if you are getting to the point where you are passing a bunch of data, you can always make the XML processor reusable and just pass the XML. It's already an encoded format